# Alterar background de uma DIV no iframe

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, upload

Seguinte pessoal,

Tenho um formulário para upload de uma imagem qualquer...

```
<form id="form-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="url" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
    <input type="submit" name="salvar" value="Salvar" />
<form>
```

Quero colocar a imagem que foi enviada, como background de uma div em um iframe, utilizando ajax, para não necessitar atualizar a página, gostaria de saber uma maneira de fazer isso, é realmente necessário o upload da imagem?

---

Meu código JS:

```
$('#form-upload').on('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: uma_url_qualquer,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("sucesso");
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim é possível e, se a imagem não deve ficar guardada para ser exibida toda vez que o usuário acessar a página, realmente nem precisa fazer o upload...

```
$('#arquivo').change(function(e) {
    var _arq = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    $("#frame").contents().find("#div").css('background-image','url('+_arq+')');
});
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/he280vrn/